# How to fix header and footer using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my iPhone and Android app, header and footer are not fixed. When I focus on input box then header and footer does not become fixed at their position. They left their position and becomes scrollable . Currently I am using :

```
$("[data-role=header] [data-role=footer]").css("position", "fixed");
```

but it does not seems to work.

Any Suggestion would be great help.

Comment: any demo you can provide?

Comment: your selector should be `$("[data-role=header],[data-role=footer]").css(...)`....use `,` in between `[data-role=header]` and `[data-role=footer]`

Comment: I have already tried this code but it does not work. Sorry by mistake I have forgot to write comma into post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.After some changes in code its working correclty

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
$("[data-role=header],[data-role=footer]").css("position", "fixed");
```

**OR**

```
$("[data-role=header]").css("position", "fixed"); 
$("[data-role=footer]").css("position", "fixed");
```

Comment: I have already tried this code but it does not work. Sorry by mistake I have forgot to write comma into post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.After some changes in code its working correclty

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
$("[data-role=header]").css("position", "fixed"); 
$("[data-role=footer]").css("position", "fixed");
```

or add `,` in between.